# Change the number of items stored in the recently used list in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do you change the number of items stored in the `File -> Open Recent` recently used list in Visual Studio Code. By default it stores 10 folders and 10 files that you have recently used.

Comment: The latest version of Visual Studio Code shows more than 10 recent opened files, if you are just seeing 10 or less is because you have not open a lot of files that will be shown in the recent opened files (Ctrl+P)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that this is currently a hardcoded limit of 10 - [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/f58289fdaf309c3ee2c45c41bf2486bfe5af25af/src/vs/code/electron-main/menus.ts#L47) is the source line on GitHub. You may want to open an issue so that there will maybe created a setting for that.

Comment: I'd like to see items which are created in VSC, and then closed to be added to the "Open Recent" list as well ...

Comment: Good call, shame they refused the request!

Answer (score 6):

**Use the `File: Open Recent` Command instead (Default `Ctrl+R`)**

As mentioned by others, the number of Entries in the Menu is hardcoded to 10, and according to the issues [#21800](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/21800) and [#25583](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/25583),  it will not change in the future.
In the welcome screen there is the `more...` button below, that uses the `File: Open Recent` command to show the whole list, but in the menu, there is no such option.

Answer (score 1):

the solution is this entry in the settings.json file:

"workbench.localHistory.maxFileEntries": 20,

or whatever value you prefer.

Comment: This appears to be related to the “Local History” feature: "When enabled, the file contents of an editor that is saved will be stored to a backup location to be able to restore or review the contents later."

Answer (score 0):

I realize it is a stale question, but I still stumbled upon it while searching how to change my list. And found an answer afterwards..

Tools/Options/Environment/General/Items to show in recently used files list

Comment: Are you perhaps missing that this question is about VS Code? :)

Comment: This answer is correct for Visual Studio 2017, but not VS Code.